# How to make Apache Spark mapPartition work correctly?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do some work based on each partitions and I would like to return the same data as input:

```
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool

rdd = sc.parallelize(["peter", "john", "harris"])
def sendPartition(iterator):
    pool = HTTPConnectionPool('ajax.googleapis.com', maxsize=10)

    for record in iterator:
        r = pool.request('GET', '/ajax/services/search/web', fields={'q': 'urllib3', 'v': '1.0'})

    return iterator


rdd.mapPartitions(sendPartition).count()
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

PS: This is only a simplification of what I am trying to achieve. I would like to do complex geosearch requests to ElasticSearch (so I cannot use the Spark Elasticsearch connector) for each element. Before this map partition, I have a huge pipelines of filters, map, etc.

PPS: I have restarted my spark and now I get "0" as the output which is better than an error, however I expected it to be "3".

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. It is not possible to reproduce the problem with code you've provided. If I had to guess at the some point in your code you have something equivalent to `sc.parallelize(None)`. On a side note Spark is not a good tool for something like this.

Comment: @zero323 I have added some details.

Comment: As far as I can tell it works just fine on 1.3-1.5 and the current master.

Comment: I have restarted my spark and now I get "0" as the output which is better than an error, however I expected it to be "3" :s.

Comment: Output should be 0. You return an empty chain for each partition.

Comment: Is it not correct to return the same iterator as the one provided? (Similar to map, but runs separately on each partition (block) of the RDD, so func must be of type Iterator<T> => Iterator<U> when running on an RDD of type T.)

Comment: It is correct, but after you execute `for record in iterator` there are no more records to read. Hence the empty RDD as the result. If you want to return `request` results as an output just use list comprehension: `return [pool.request(...) for record in iterator]`.

Comment: If I would like to avoid using a list comprehension because I have some advanced processing to do, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93826/discussion-between-zero323-and-poiuytrez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding type error it doesn't look like it can be reproduced using code included in the question. My guess is at some point `None` value has been either passed to `RDD` constructor or returned from `sendPartition`.

Problem with empty RDD as an output is a result of the way how you use partition iterator. PySpark is using `itertools.chain` to pass data to the `mapPartition` which behaves pretty more or less the same way a Scala `Iterator`.

```
import itertools

iter = itertools.chain(range(10))
iter.next()
## 0
```

After you finish a `for` loop

```
for x in iter:
    x
```

you end up with an empty `chain`:

```
type(iter)
## itertools.chain

iter.nex()
## Traceback (most recent call last)
##     ...
## StopIteration:
```

While `StopIteration` is handled as a part of normal iteration logic there is no data to return.

There a few ways to handle this where the cleanest is to extract a function and use list comprehension

```
def make_request(record, pool):
    r = pool.request('GET', '/ajax/services/search/web',
        fields={'q': 'urllib3', 'v': '1.0'})
    return r.read() # Or any other data you need.

def sendPartition(iterator):
    pool = HTTPConnectionPool('ajax.googleapis.com', maxsize=10)
    return [make_request(record, pool) for record in iterator]
```

Please note that if you want to use connection pool you have to read data before you exit `mapPartitions`.  It means no lazy evaluation (like generators). Personally I would consider asynchronous requests (for example with `async/await` in 3.5, RxPy elsewhere) inside partition and evaluating before you exit.