# How to use long-lived expensive-to-instantiate utility services where executors run?

Tags: apache-spark

My Spark processing logic depends upon long-lived, expensive-to-instantiate utility objects to perform data-persistence operations. Not only are these objects probably not `Serializable`, but it is probably impractical to distribute their state in any case, as said state likely includes stateful network connections.

What I would like to do instead is instantiate these objects *locally* within each executor, or locally within threads spawned by each executor. (Either alternative is acceptable, as long as the instantiation does not take place on each tuple in the RDD.)

Is there a way to write my Spark driver program such that it directs executors to invoke a function to instantiate an object locally (and cache it in the executor's local JVM memory space), rather than instantiating it within the driver program then attempting to serialize and distribute it to the executors?

Comment: I suspect that my question is related to (or at least could help answer) this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794316/how-to-call-services-from-spark-worker-processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to share objects at partition level:

I've tried this : [How to make Apache Spark mapPartition work correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439655/how-to-make-apache-spark-mappartition-work-correctly)

The repartition to make numPartitions match a multiple of the number of executors.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind originally, but it does work well for my use case. Thanks for the tip.